# How to change image with fade effect fast?

Tags: vb.net, image, animation, fade

I used this:

```
Dim i1 As Bitmap = owall.Clone
    Dim i2 As New Bitmap(ChangingWP)

    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(i1)

    Dim cm As New Imaging.ColorMatrix(New Single()() { _
                                                     New Single() {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, _
                                                     New Single() {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, _
                                                     New Single() {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, _
                                                     New Single() {0, 0, 0, current_alpha, 0}, _
                                                     New Single() {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}})

    Dim ia As New Imaging.ImageAttributes
    ia.SetColorMatrix(cm, Imaging.ColorMatrixFlag.Default, Imaging.ColorAdjustType.Bitmap)

    g.DrawImage(i2, New Rectangle(0, 0, i2.Width, i2.Height), 0, 0, i2.Width, i2.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia)
    g.Dispose()

    If increase Then
        current_alpha += Speed
    Else
        current_alpha -= Speed
    End If

    SetWallpaper(i1, Layout)
    If current_alpha >= 1 Then
        current_alpha = 1
        tmrBlend.Enabled = False
        SetWallpaper(ChangingWP, Layout)
    ElseIf current_alpha <= 0 Then
        current_alpha = 0
        tmrBlend.Enabled = False
    End If
```

But it is not fast.Do you have any ideas?
Actually,I'm trying to change wallpaper with fade effect.

Answer (score -1):

What about changing the `Opacity` property of the control displaying the image, instead of altering the image itself?

Comment: There are no control to change the Opacity of. The question says the code are changeing the wallpaper for the desktop, not a picture in an winform-control.